# Avoiding Exception Value: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object in Django signals

Tags: python, django

I need to create an `invoice` object whenever an `invoice` is created from inside `post_save.connect(after_saving_invoice, sender=Invoice)`. This is causing `Exception Value: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.

The reason of the exception is clear but how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter your need.  "Overcoming" the recursion would just mean that you succeed at creating infinite objects, which is inadvisable.

If what you *really* need is to create a second `Invoice` *only when the first one was created manually*, well, that's different.  Make your function do nothing unless the sender is manually-created.  If you really can't tell the difference between manual and automatic, add a field that tells you.  (Though surely there's *something* unique about the automatic objects, or you wouldn't need to create them!)